# Check if given number is fibonacci in C

Tags: c, algorithm

How to check if a given number is a Fibonacci number?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int isPerfectSquare(int x) {
  int s = sqrt(x);
  return (s * s == x);
}
int isFibonacci(int n) {
  return isPerfectSquare(5 * n * n + 4) || isPerfectSquare(5 * n * n - 4);
}

void main() {
  isFibonacci(4) ? printf("%d yes\n", 4) : printf("%d no\n", 4);
  isFibonacci(-35) ? printf("%d yes\n", -35) : printf("%d no\n", -35);
  isFibonacci(9227465) ? printf("%d yes\n", 9227465): printf("%d no\n", 9227465);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
4 no
-35 no
9227465 no
```

[online tool for checking fibonacci](https://ibb.co/YPyCBFC)

This algorithm doesn't work for longer integer numbers? How to fix it to work for all possible integer numbers(range between `-2147483647 -1` and `2147483647`?

Comment: What is the range of inputs for `n`?

Comment: You may be interested in [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet's_formula), which doesn't require iterations to compute Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: minimum is -2147483647 -1, and maximum is 2147483647

Comment: There are only 46 Fibonacci numbers between `-2147483647 -1` and `2147483647` (give or take, allowing for *off-by-one* error). I suggest a [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) :)

Comment: how to check does given number belongs to fibonacci sequence?

Comment: It's easier to just iterate and check if the number if a Fibonacci number or not, since they're very few in quantity in the given range (as highlighted by @pmg)

Comment: @ikegami it will be `sqrt(121) (or 129)`. `n^2` would evaluate to `125` for `-5`

Comment: @Abhinav Mathur, oops. n=-5 was a confusing choice of my part. In my head, I changed to 5 * n * n to -(5^3). Comment deleted.

Comment: Re "*This algorithm doesn't work for negative numbers*", [It does work](https://godbolt.org/z/Yq7a65951)

Comment: `void main()` is wrong. It should be `int main()`

Comment: @ikegami you're right for negative, it works for negative, but void main is the same as int main in this case, and in most cases

Comment: @devec, `void main()` is *not* the same as `int main()`.  The former is wrong, and the latter is right.  `int main(void)` would be even more right, or else `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.  These two and their semantic equivalents are the only signatures that a strictly conforming C program for a hosted environment may use.

Comment: I added answer, another approach suggested from comments

Comment: You need [the inverse Binet formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4341161/735404). Then it's just an O(1) operation.

Comment: @mouviciel Isn't the Binet formula already being used by the OP?

Comment: @JohnBollinger `void main()` may be allowed under "... or in some other implementation-defined manner." C17dr § 5.1.2.2.1 1.  I suppose it would take a LL discussion to flesh that out. IAC, `main()` signature here is a minor point.

Comment: Yes, @chux-ReinstateMonica, and a program that relies on that therefore fails to be strictly conforming.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Interesting, "A strictly conforming program shall use only those features of the language and library specified in this International Standard. It shall not produce output dependent on any unspecified, undefined, or **implementation-defined behavior**, and shall not exceed any minimum implementation limit." C17dr § 4 1.

Comment: Yes, @chux-ReinstateMonica, and what is your point about that? I contend that if the program uses a non-standard signature for `main()` and it produces any output at all, then that constitutes producing output dependent on implementation-defined behavior.  I also characterize the allowed signatures of `main()` to be a language feature.  And I certainly consider a program that works only on implementations that provide a certain language extension to be outside the intended interpretation of "strictly conforming".

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am agreeing that OP's code is not strictly conforming.  I agree `void main()` is _better_ as `int main()`. I do not agree that it is _wrong_ if OP's compiler allows it.  It is simply not good coding practice nor portable.

Comment: I see now, @chux-ReinstateMonica, and I agree with that.  But I was not saying that the OP's compiler was wrong to accept that form; rather, I was saying that the OP was wrong to write it.  That is perhaps a little too strong, but if it had been successful in avoiding the detailed delve into exactly what is and is not wrong with it, then I would not have lost any sleep over the imprecision.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the implementation you have does work for negative numbers. It only fails for large numbers.

To work with inputs in the inclusive range [-2,147,483,648, 2,147,483,647], you need to accommodate numbers as large as 5 * -2,147,483,648 * -2,147,483,648 + 4. This requires 65 bit of precision as a floating point number. This is *quite* large, and would probably involve specialized libraries.

However, the largest fibonacci number in this range is 1,836,311,903. So if we check if |n| ≤ 1,836,311,903, we only need 64 bits of precision. A `long double` on an x86 would be large enough if it's implemented as [x86's extended precision format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format), so switching to using `long double` instead of `double` could work.

```
int isPerfectSquare( int64_t x ) {
   int64_t r = llroundl( sqrtl( x ) );
   return r * r == x;
}

int isFibonacci( int32_t x ) {
   if ( x > 1836311903 || x < -1836311903 )
      return 0;

   int64_t t = ((int64_t)5) * x * x;
   if ( isPerfectSquare( t + 4 ) )
      return 1;
   if ( isPerfectSquare( t - 4 ) )
      return 1;

   return 0;
}
```

The use `llroundl` was added to compensate for deviations in the results of `sqrtl`.

---

That's the math approach. The CS approach is to build a [table](https://miniwebtool.com/list-of-fibonacci-numbers/?number=47) of all 47 fibonacci numbers from 0 to 1,836,311,903, a perform a binary search on them.

Comment: Unfortunately `sqrt` is going to return a `double` which only has 53 bits of precision, so you still have a problem. The binary search suggestion is solid though.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, I know. That's why I said to use `sqrtl` instead of `sqrt`

Comment: I don't see that suggestion in the answer anywhere.

Comment: @Mark Random: Then look again??? "(`sqrt` would be replaced with `sqrtl`.)"

Comment: No fair referring to recent edits that I haven't seen yet.

Comment: The addition of that quotes was made 9 minutes before your comment. And it even if I didn't mention it, it's literally the only operation that uses/returns a double, so obviously switching to working with long double would requires switching to `sqrtl`. (The fact that it doesn't need to be mentioned is why it's in parens.)

Comment: It *does* need to be mentioned, because not everyone is aware of it. I certainly wasn't.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, That's not relevant. I had already specified it would need to be changed. That fact that you would have to look up the name of the long double version if I didn't mention its name doesn't mean it needs to be mentioned. But I did mention it because I'm nice :)

Comment: I didn't say I didn't know the name of the function, I was unaware it even existed. I'm sure I'm not alone. And certainly `long double` isn't going to exist on every platform. P.S. don't get me wrong, I do appreciate your edit.

Comment: @MarkRansom Perhaps you and ikegami could delete the now `sqrt(l)` discourse.

Comment: Re "*I was unaware it even existed*", My answer made you aware of it when it suggested using long doubles! So like I said, the only think the edit did was save you from looking up its name.

Comment: Re "*And certainly long double isn't going to exist on every platform.*", Why wouldn't it? Whether it has enough precision or not is another issue, but that's already covered by the answer.

Comment: 2 shortcomings: Using `long double` math does rely on the "long double ... would be large enough if it's implemented as x86's extended precision format" or something wider as noted in this answer. C allows `long double` the same range as `double` which is not enough here. `sqrt(l)()` are  not certainly implemented well to give the best FP answer & risk incorrect functionality in the `s * s == x` test. `s = sqrtl( x )` as `s = roundl(sqrtl( x ))` would help in many cases. Even better, use integer only math in `isPerfectSquare()` - various solution on the web. Other than that, a good answer.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica, i don't think `roundl` would work here. It could give a false positive. /// The fact that `long double` might not be good enough depending on the platform/compiler was already mentioned.

Comment: No, it would work. Adding.

Comment: On refection, perhaps `long long s = llroundl( sqrtl( x ) ); return s * s == x;` would be best.

Comment: @ikegami could you add the whole code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

Create array of Fibonacci numbers, and check for every number if it belongs to array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int is_fibonacci(int arr[], size_t n, int num) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (arr[i] == num || arr[i] == -num)
      return 1;
  return 0;
}
int main() {
  size_t n = 47;
  int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, nextTerm, arr[47];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = n1;
    nextTerm = n1 + n2;
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = nextTerm;
  }
  is_fibonacci(arr, n, 4) ? printf("%d yes\n", 4): printf("%d no\n", 4);
  is_fibonacci(arr, n, -5) ? printf("%d yes\n", -5): printf("%d no\n", -5);
  is_fibonacci(arr, n, -123456789) ? printf("%d yes\n", -123456789): printf("%d no\n", -123456789);
  is_fibonacci(arr, n, 9227465) ? printf("%d yes\n", 9227465): printf("%d no\n", 9227465);
  return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
4 no
-5 yes
-123456789 no
9227465 yes
```

Comment: why `size_t n=48`?

Comment: devec, `n` could have been `char, unsigned short, long long` or any sort of integer type as only a small range is needed here.  `size_t` is the not-too-narrow, not-too-wide type for array indexing and sizing in all cases.  It should be the default type to use for that unless you have compelling requirements otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, it should be 47. The original code populated 1..46 (wrong), and searched 0..45 (also wrong). That means it relied on undefined behaviour, and it wasn't finding 1,134,903,170 or 1,836,311,903 as a fibonacci. It should populate and search 0..46. And this is done by using n=47. This is a bug in my fix. Fixed.

Comment: [My test](https://godbolt.org/z/hvz8eP6vK), btw. Note the correct use of `int64_t` instead of `int` (which could be as small as 16 bit, and is only 32 bit on the test platform).

Comment: 46 is enough, because if it goes from i = 0 to i < 46, it would be 46 numbers exactly, and there are 46 fibonacci numbers that can store integer value

Comment: No, [there are 47 of them](https://miniwebtool.com/list-of-fibonacci-numbers/?number=47) (not counting the negative ones).